# lucene main function not found

Tags: java, lucene

I was running lucene library for my text analysis project (I am relatively new to java). There is problem with main function (or command).

The lucene version I am using is 3.0.0, and is already compiled into a JAR file. The JAR file is in the same folder as the main class file Indexer.java.

I first run the compile code:

```
javac -cp \lucene-core-3.0.0.jar Indexer.java
```

and it worked correctly and created the Indexer.class file in the same directory.

Then I run the same sort of command:

```
java -cp \lucene-core.3.0.0.jar Indexer
```

This time the command line output says I don't have the main class Indexer:

```
could not find or load main class Indexer
```

I checked the original java code, there is main method defined:

```
import org.apache.lucene.index.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;


import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.*;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;

import java.io.FileReader;


public class Indexer {

private IndexWriter writer;

private void indexFile(File f) throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Indexing " + f.getCanonicalPath());
    Document doc = getDocument(f);
    if(doc != null){
        writer.addDocument(doc);
    }
}

public Indexer(String IndexDir) throws IOException{
    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(IndexDir));
    writer = new IndexWriter(dir,new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30),
                                        true,IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
}


protected Document getDocument(File f) throws Exception{
    Document doc = new Document();

    doc.add(new Field("contents", new FileReader(f)));
    doc.add(new Field("filename",
                        f.getName(), 
                        Field.Store.YES,
                        Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    doc.add(new Field("fullpath",
                        f.getCanonicalPath(),
                        Field.Store.YES,
                        Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    return doc;
}

protected boolean acceptFile(File f){
    return f.getName().endsWith(".txt");
}


public int index(String dataDir) throws Exception{

    File[] files = new File(dataDir).listFiles();


    for(int i = 0; i < files.length;i++){
        File f = files[i];

        if(!f.isDirectory() 
            && !f.isHidden() 
            && f.exists()
            && f.canRead()
            && acceptFile(f)){
            indexFile(f);
        }
    }
    return writer.numDocs();
}

public void close() throws IOException{
    writer.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    if(args.length != 2){
        throw new Exception("Usage: java " + Indexer.class.getName()+" <index dir><data dir");
    }

    String indexDir = args[0];
    String dataDir = args[1];

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Indexer indexer = new Indexer(indexDir);
    int numIndexed = indexer.index(dataDir);
    indexer.close();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Indexing " + 
            numIndexed + " files took " + (end-start)+ " milliseconds.");


}

}
```

What is wrong with my code/command?

Answer (score 0):

The jvm doesn't include the current directory in the runtime classpath when one is explicitly specified. Try

```
java -cp ".:lucene-core.3.0.0.jar" Indexer
```

Comment: It seems like the code produces "-bash: lucene-core.3.0.0.jar: command not found" error

Comment: Thanks! I made a silly mistake. But with : it still produces 'could not find or load main class' error.  Really confusing.

Comment: Does your class have a `package` declaration>

Comment: No. I wrote it in eclipse and the package is set to default when creating the class.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I used Cygwin and there is some crapy syntax with the command, which means I need to add double quotes on the class path and every argument passed.